# Facebook API For Pulling Reviews

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

Has anyone seen a full example of how to pull facebook reviews using the graph api.

According to the docs:
A page access token is required to retrieve this data.

I have code that asks a user to login already and gets an auth token which I can use to post a message to their facebook feed. Is there an additional step I need to do to be able to read their reviews/ratings?

Here is an example of the code to post to their feed/page.

```
response = Curl.post("https://graph.facebook.com/#{page_id}/feed", {
    :message => message,
    :access_token => auth_token
  })
```

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 14):

If you're referring to Page Ratings (different from App Reviews!), then the endpoint is

```
GET /{page_id}/ratings
```

as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings You'll need a Page Access Token for this.

Where I get a little bit confused is that you mention that you want to

> read their reviews/ratings

In that case it's something else, because afaik it's currently not possible to query the User's Page ratings via Graph API or FQL. It<s>'s</s> was only possible to query App Reviews via FQL <s>(see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/review/)</s> (Update: FQL is no longer available since 2016)

Comment: how to get that page_id? @Tobi

Comment: page_id is the page url, such as https://facebook.com/ExamplePage/

The page_id in this example would be ExamplePage

Comment: Anyone else notice that the field reviewer does not return any data?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/recommendation/

Comment: @AndrewSchultz AFAIK: The reviewer field now requires you to use a live version of the app with "manage_pages"-permissions. If you use an app that is in developer mode the reviewer field is empty unless the reviewer is a user of the app. I hope this gets solved because I doubt facebook will grant me access to manage_pages live.

Comment: Is there a way to get review id along with the response?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set permission in the app to access the {GET /{page_id}/ratings} API. The permission is common for
/page/comments,
/page/posts,
/page/ratings,
/page/tagged,
and the permission name is "pages_read_user_content"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_user_content